# Can 't change text-fill at List Cell

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I can't change text color at my `listView` -> `listCell` . I use CSS for styling. I am sure I selected it properly in CSS because changing background works fine. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. There was a brute-force setStyle(-fx-text-fill: white) in my custom ListCell class

Comment: I would never refer to using `setStyle()` as "brute-force." That is what it's intended for :)

Comment: Sorry for my expression. It's just unwanted in my project because everything should be editable through external CSS